# jQuery animate() and easing type

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing

I have this:

```
$('h1').animate({
    //stuff to be changed,
}, {
    duration: 1000, 
    queue: false
})
```

It doesn't accept when I change it to something like this:

```
{
    duration: 1000, 
    queue: false, 
    easing: easeOutBounce
}
```

When providing the `easing` as a string, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

How should I place the easing type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easing should be a string, like so:

```
{
    duration: 1000,
    queue: false,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce'
}
```

The API Docs on [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) state:

> **easing** (default: `swing`)
>
> Type: **String**
>
> A string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.

Comment: Tried it before. This comes out:
Uncaught TypeError: n.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: @Dawid it sounds like you need to include the jQueryUI library; easing options are not a standard part of jQuery

Comment: @Dawid Add `jquery.ui.min.js` or `jquery.easing.min.js` to solve your problem.

Comment: How could I forget about the UI include
Thanks a lot